# Is it possible to access the product name from a custom action? If so, how?

Tags: wix

I have a wix C# custom action, and I'd like it to use the product name i.e:

```
...
<Product Name="ThisGuyRightHere" ... >
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, simply by using this session["ProductName"].

Comment: If it's a deferred CA it'll need to be accessed via CustomActionData.